# How to get a specific set out of an array with json objects with angular

Tags: angular

Good evening,

I have an array of json objects and i am able to display them with angular one by one (in this care I am creating a blog ). I get the array of json object with a HTTP GET.

So I have a landing page and that displays blog tittle and teasertext, when i click on the teasertext i want to jump to a detail page for that specific blog where you can see the long text.

I have created the service, and the components. When i click on the teasertext I see in the adressbar it has the correct ID of the post i clicked on (i am using mongoDB so the ID is rather big :) )

I suspect the error is in the method , but I am stuck with it. Reading and displaying the whole array was easy, displaying a specific set has me stumped. As I mentioned if i click on the post i want the details of I see the _id of the post in the adressbar as i would expect, like so:

`http://127.0.0.1/goals/detail/5ed81b205822000001007632`

So how do i get Angular to give me the records of only that specific json. so i can use it in the html like:  `Details off:  {{blog.title}}` etc etc

My components is:
blog-detail.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Blog } from 'src/app/core/models/blog';
import { BlogService } from 'src/app/core/services/blog.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
//import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-detail',
  templateUrl: './blog-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-detail.component.css']

})
export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() blog: Blog;
  pageTitle: string = 'Blog Detail';
  blogList: Blog[];


constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private blogservice: BlogService,

) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getBlogs();
}

getBlogs(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
  this.blogservice.getBlogs()
    .subscribe(blog => this.blogList = blog);
}


}
```

My blogservice is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Blog } from '../models/blog';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogService {
  private blogUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/blog';  // URL to web api
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    getBlogs(): Observable<Blog[]> {
      return this.http.get<Blog[]>(this.blogUrl);
    }


  }
```

The result from the http get is: something like

```
{"_id":"5ed81b205822000001007632","title":"Title blog 1","content":"Main blog text with pictures and stuff.","updated_at":"2020-06-07 03:58:58","created_at":"2020-06-03 21:50:24","shorttext":"teaser text","created_by":"user 1"},{"_id":"5ed81b2b5822000001007633","title":"Title blog 2","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","updated_at":"2020-06-07 06:49:39","created_at":"2020-06-03 21:50:35","shorttext":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, teaser text","created_by":"user 2"}]
```

EDIT: I now created an extra methode in my service:

```
 /** GET blog by id. **/
    getBlogDetail(_id: string): Observable<Blog> {
    const url = `${this.blogUrl}/${_id}`;
    return this.http.get<Blog>(url);
  }
```

and used that in in the component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getBlogDetail();
}

getBlogDetail(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
  this.blogservice.getBlogs()
    .subscribe(blog => this.blogList = blog);
}
```

But i still cant get it to work.

Comment: so you want to display a specific item from the array as Blog ?

Comment: I want to take the specific parts of the array and display them in separate divs. So the main page only would have blog title and a short text, the detail page would have title, long text author etc

Comment: To Clarify even more: The divs would for instance be filled by using ```{{ blog.title}} ```and ```{{blog.content}}``` like I do on my main page, but there i just loop through the whole array. In the details page i only want the info that belongs to the specific article

Comment: Let's get one step back. How do you get the initial list of Blogs and what kind of information do you already have then? Do you get a list of the same object type as shown right above your edit?

Comment: That's correct the array just above my edit is gotten with an http get, and with angular I can easily cycle through the whole array. So every cycle I display title, author etc. I could display all the details for all the articles, but that would make the landing page to become very messy. So I want to only display title and short text and wehn you click on it it will display everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-cqqczj) you can use as service with stringfiying object but you loose data if refresh page

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("");
  getParam = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:string) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

you can use `localStorage` with stringying object if in same tab, you loose data if open new browser

or you can call api in page with related id to get details (recommended)

```
getBlogDetail(): void {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogId');
  this.blogservice.getBlogDetail(id)
    .subscribe(blog => console.log(blog));
}
```

Comment: How to I call the api with the related I'd?

Comment: you need to  write one more method in api part such as  how u get list but in this scenario u will filter your result with id you send to api and take object from api

Comment: Hi pc_coder, isn't that what I am trying to do with the new method I created? (my edit)? It doesn't seem to achieve a result (no doubt user error )  /** GET blog by id. **/
    getBlogDetail(_id: string): Observable<Blog> {
    const url = `${this.blogUrl}/${_id}`;
    return this.http.get<Blog>(url);
  }

Comment: yes this is. Is method gives any result to u ? I updated answer can u see anything in console?

Comment: I get the following error in the log ``` GET http://127.0.0.1/blog/null 404 (Not Found) ``` It is doing a whole new get to the url, but i want it to filter the data in the array for that specific json. Also in stead of the _id, i see "null" in the url so its not reading the ID anyway.

Comment: Maybe a good thing to add is that the backend is laravel, which creates the get with all the output.

[{"_id":"5ed81b205822000001007632","title":"Title blog 1","content":"Main blog text with pictures and stuff.","updated_at":"2020-06-07 03:58:58","created_at":"2020-06-03 21:50:24","shorttext":"teaser text","created_by":"user 1"}] (this is just one record in the json

Comment: I now changed my service method to:

/** GET blog by id v2.  */
  getBlogDetail<Data>(_id: string): Observable<Blog> {
    const url = `${this.blogUrl}/?id=${_id}`;
    return this.http.get<Blog[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(blog => blog[0]), // returns a {0|1} element array
        
      );
  } 

In my component i now have:
`getBlogDetail(): void {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
  this.blogservice.getBlogDetail(id)
    .subscribe(blog => console.log(blog));

} `

The console still says 404, instead of filtering the array

Comment: OK!: I got a little further, Laravel now gets me a specific detail when  i go to:
http://127.0.0.1/post/5ed81b205822000001007632

I changed my service and included an extra url for a get * private blogUrlDetail= 'http://127.0.0.1/post'; * 

The method in the service now is: * /** GET blog by id. **/
    getBlogDetail(_id: string): Observable<Blog> {
    const url = `${this.blogUrlDetail}/${_id}`;
    return this.http.get<Blog>(url);
  } *

 However in console i still see: * GET http://127.0.0.1/post/null 404 (Not Found) * 

So it is not passing in the _id.

Comment: can you share approuting in question also  ?

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blog', component: BlogListComponent},

  {path: 'detail/:blogId', component: BlogDetailComponent},

  {path: 'create-blog', component: CreateBlogComponent}

];

Comment: Just to clarfiy (if needed), when i click on the details, Angular takes me to a details page in this case: 
http://127.0.0.1/goals/detail/5ed81b205822000001007632

Laravel allows a get to, in this case,: http://127.0.0.1/post/5ed81b205822000001007632, which will give me the specific json of this article. 

However the GET angular does is:  http://127.0.0.1/post/null

Answer (score 0):

5ed81b205822000001007632 using this id you need make a new api call for getting particular id data.there is no other options.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean? I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

pc_coder's answers help a lot and pointed me in the right direction. I had to take several more steps I realised from my initial attempts

First of all i had to get laravel to allow a GET to a specific blogId. (this was achieved with a fairly simple function in Laravel `public function form($_id = false){
        if($_id){
            $data = Post::findOrFail($_id);
            return  $data;` 
Inside the controller that manages the posts. Besides this function i had to add a route `Route::get('/post/{_id?}', 'PostController@form')->name('post.form');` 
in laravel. These 2 things setup the url for the get.

On the angular side I was still struggling to pass the _id to the url, PC-Coder's question about the routes pointed me in the right direction. I noticed the route actually was

`{path: 'detail/:blogId', component: BlogDetailComponent}`
So i did two things, first of all i made a second url: `private blogUrlDetail= 'http://127.0.0.1/post';` , this was to point to the right 1st part of the GET address, and next i realised that passing _id wasn't correct *hence the "NULL" i was getting all the time, but that it should be "blogId".

The function in the service now became:

````
    getBlogDetail(blogId: string): Observable<Blog> {
    const url = `${this.blogUrlDetail}/${blogId}`;
    return this.http.get<Blog>(url);
  } ```

The class in the blog-detail-component now became:
`` export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() blog: Blog;
  pageTitle: string = 'Blog Detail';
  blogList: Blog[];


constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private blogservice: BlogService,

) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getBlogDetail();

}

getBlogDetail(): void {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogId');
  this.blogservice.getBlogDetail(id)
    .subscribe(blog => this.blog = blog)
}```

Now i can just get all the fields with {{ blog.title}}, {{ blog.content }} etc

Thanks pc_coder. your help is very much apreciated.
````